# Why are these principal value integrals equal

Tags: complex-analysis

I am doing an integral problem and encountered this scenario:
$$\text{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{2e^{-(2+\pi)t}}{e^{-2 \pi t}+1}dt=\text{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{2e^{(2+\pi)t}}{e^{2 \pi t}+1}dt$$

Can someone explain to me why the principal values of these two integrals are equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that by using the substitution $t\mapsto -t$ we have

$$
\int_{-M}^M \frac{2e^{-(2+\pi)t}}{e^{-2\pi t}+1}\mathrm dt=
-\int_{M}^{-M}\frac{2e^{(2+\pi)t}}{e^{2\pi t}+1}\mathrm dt\\
=\int_{-M}^{M}\frac{2e^{(2+\pi)t}}{e^{2\pi t}+1}\mathrm dt\\
$$
Now take $M\to \infty$.